# Improving a convergence bound for Newton's method applied to an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the fifth part of an exercise on generalizing Newton's method to analytic functions in Narasimhan and Nievergelt's Complex Analysis in One Variable (p134.5).

Let f be an analytic function. Define Newton's iteration to be:
$$
z_{n+1} = z_n - f(z_n)/f'(z_n)
$$

Suppose $f(z_*) = 0$, and on a closed disk of radius R centered at $z_*$, $\overline{D(z_*,R)}$, we also know $f'(z) \ne 0$. Also define:
$$
m = min \{|f'(z)| : z \in \overline{D(z_*,R)}\} \\
M = max \{|f''(z)| : z \in \overline{D(z_*,R)}\} \\
$$
The claim is that if $2m/M < 1$ and $|z_0 - z_*| < \sqrt{2m/M}$, we have the bound:
$$
|z_n - z_*| \le C^{2^n-1} M/2m \tag{*}\label{*}
$$
where $C = |z_0 - z_*|\sqrt{M/2m}$.

It's not mentioned explicitly in the problem but I'm assuming that also $R > 1$ or really any similar assumption would be fine by me since I'm not making much progress.

So far as my attempt goes, in an earlier part of the problem I have gotten,
$$
|z_{n+1} - z_*| \le (M/2m)|z_n - z_*|^2 \tag{**}\label{**}
$$
using a bound on the remainder of a Taylor's expansion about $z_*$,
$$
f(z) = f(z_*) + f'(z_*)(z-z_*) + R_f(z) \\
|R_f(z)| \le M|z-z_*|^2/2
$$

This $\ref{**}$ and induction was enough to get the "not improved" bound given in (p135.4),
$$
|z_n - z_*| \le D^{2^n-1} |z_0 - z_*| \\
D = |z_0 - z_*|M/2m
$$
when $|z_0 - z_*| \lt min\{R,2m/M\}$

If I just try induction again directly to $\ref{*}$, it doesn't work. I can instead try something like, assume for some n,
$$
|z_n - z_*| \le C^{2^n-1} \sqrt{2m/M} |z_0 - z_*| \tag{a}\label{a}
$$
Then $\ref{**}$ gives,
$$
|z_{n+1} - z_*| \le (M/2m)|z_n - z_*|^2 \le (M/2m) C^{2^{n+1}-1} (2m/M) |z_0 - z_*|^2 / C \\
= C^{2^{n+1}-1} \sqrt{2m/M} |z_0 - z_*|
$$
so if I had an $n$ where $\ref{a}$ held I'd be able to get $\ref{*}$ for all the larger $n$, since $\sqrt{2m/M}|z_0-z_*| \lt 1 \lt M/2m$. I don't think any of what I have available right now suggests it would hold for small $n$ though.

$\ref{*}$ does at least hold for $n=1$ directly using just the bound $|z_0-z_*| \lt \sqrt{2m/M}$ and $\ref{**}$, but that's also not much progress. Any help would be appreciated.